# Kotlin chain of responsibility pattern with generics

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin, chain-of-responsibility

Using the chain of responsibility pattern I ran into a problem where next chain element was expected to have the same generic type of the first element. I know **why** this happens: The first handler expects the second handler to use the generic type "Apple". I just don't know exactly how to solve it.

There is an answer on how to [handle it in java here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292118/chain-of-responsibility-handler-with-java-generics), but since java doesn't have reified types and all that the approach should look different in Kotlin, right?

There are different options that come to my mind:

1. Don't use generics - would lead to casting the collection types to specific subtypes and wouldn't look clean
2. Try to use reified types (how?)

To illustrate the problem I am posting a demo code below.

---

```
data class Apple(val name:String, val color:Int) 
data class Orange(val circumference:Double)

object Main{
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val first = FirstHandler()
        val second = SecondHandler()
        first.setNextHandler(second)  // !!! wrong type here since <Apple> is expected
        first.process()
    } 
}

abstract class ChainHandler<T>{
    protected var nextHandlerInChain:ChainHandler<T>? = null
    fun setNextHandler(handler: ChainHandler<T>): ChainHandler<T> {
        this.nextHandlerInChain = handler
        return handler
    }

    abstract fun peel(): Collection<T>
    abstract fun process():MutableMap<String,Any> }

class FirstHandler : ChainHandler<Apple>() {
    override fun peel(): Collection<Apple> {
        return Collections.emptyList<Apple>()
    }
    override fun process(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
        val peeledApples = peel()
        val map = nextHandlerInChain?.process()
        map?.put("apples",peeledApples) ?:kotlin.run {
            val map = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
            map.put("apples",peeledApples)
        }
        return map!!
    } }

class SecondHandler : ChainHandler<Orange>() {
    override fun peel(): Collection<Orange> {
        return Collections.emptyList<Orange>()
    }
    override fun process(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
        val peeledOranges = peel()
        val map = nextHandlerInChain?.process()
        map?.put("oranges",peeledOranges) ?:kotlin.run {
            val map = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
            map.put("oranges",peeledOranges)
        }
        return map!!
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin has something called a star projection that might help you here. It basically tells the compiler that you don't really care what type of `ChainHandler` you get. You can use it to make your `setNextHandler` compile, like this:

```
abstract class ChainHandler<T>{
  // Note the star projection here
  protected var nextHandlerInChain: ChainHandler<*>? = null

  // Defining a type parameter S, so that the return type is equal to the input type.
  fun <S> setNextHandler(handler: ChainHandler<S>): ChainHandler<S> {
    this.nextHandlerInChain = handler
    return handler
  }

  ...
}
```

You can read more about star projections here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections

As for reifying the type parameter: Reified type parameters work only for inline functions. Not for type parameters on a class.

Answer (score 2):

This very much depends on specifics of how you want handlers to interact. For this code, just changing the type of next handler (in both `var nextHandlerInChain` and `fun setNextHandler` to `ChainHandler<*>` would work, since `process()` returns something independent of `T` anyway.